# selecting a field when you cannot count from the start

Tags: cut

I have a long file ( 20000+ lines) where each of the lines is a description of a book:

```
 book_number "title of the book" size type author_number
```

Where the element in quotes is a string with quotes and the others are numbers, except for type which is a single word:

```
 23446 Raising Steam 537724 EPUB 4
```

I want to extract all the size fields but using cut you cannot use negative numbers to count from the back of the result of splitting with `-d " "`:

```
 cut -d " " -f -2 books.txt
```

I cannot count from the front as the books may have any number of spaces in the title (I did not make up this format, I would have used CSV or JSON which require quoting).

Am I missing some option that allows using `cut`? What else could I use to get the second-before-last field with a one line solution?

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that, do I need to delete this question?

Comment: No reason to, it has just been marked as a duplicate, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With python you can do this (note `-3`):

```
 python -c "for x in open('books.txt'): print x.split(' ')[-3]"
```

or with `awk`:

```
 awk '{ print ( $(NF-2) ) }' books.txt
```

Comment: I like the Python one-liner, never used it that way.